# Android LinearLayout with 2 content, one should take 30dp and another the rest

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, android-linearlayout

I have vertical linearLayout. First element is a framelayout that has some content and second element is button that should always be at the very bottom.

While button should be at the bottom, the framelayout should take the rest space that is in the linearlayout

Comment: Could you add your code what you tried?

Answer (score 3):

```
<LinearLayout
    ...>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        ...

    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        .../>

</LinearLayout>
```

The key to this solution is the combination of `0dp` height for your `FrameLayout` and the `layout_weight` attribute. This attribute allows a `LinearLayout` to divide the "extra" space up between its children. Your button takes up a fixed amount of space, and your `FrameLayout` takes up no space at all... so everything that *isn't* the button winds up being given to the `FrameLayout` and now it fills up the whole `LinearLayout` while leaving enough space for the `Button` below it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:layout_height="match_parent"` on your `FrameLayout`

Answer (score 1):

you should use RelativeLayout somthing Like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/btnTest"
        />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_above="@id/btnTest"
        >

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```